# How can I write a driver for an asus trackpad on linux?

Tags: linux, driver, linux-device-driver

I bought a laptop and installed Linux on it and the trackpad is now not working but it was on Windows. There is no linux driver for it and I thought this could be a good project to write one.

I have read and implemented tutorials on device drivers for simple things (turning on an led on a pandaboard) but I have no idea where to start here. Related questions pointed to commands like `modprobe -r psmouse` and it seems the trackpad is not seen at all.

Any idea ? the laptop is : Asus R409C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary fix is to boot with "psmouse.proto=bare" on the kernel cmdline.

```
$ sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to add psmouse.proto=bare at the end, and save your modifications.

Then:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

And finally reboot.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question but solves my problem. just doing this and the trackpad is now working. could you say what's going on under the hood here ?

Comment: the question is still on, for example there is no scroll implemented on this trackpad (2 fingers) but there was one on windows

Answer (score 0):

i think linux input subsystem can be used to write driver for touchpad. Exact details need to be considered. But most of the input devices can be integrated using input subsystem.

Comment: I have read some docs about the input subsystem, but I can't figure out where the primary input comes from. I mean the trackpad has to send the touch events to somewhere, and where is it ?